# Struts2 Textarea Resize

Tags: html, css, struts2

Basically what I'm trying to do is 'hide' the resize handle on a Struts2 Textarea. But with my attempt at it I had and unexpected result. With my code I told it to overflow in the x & y direction with a scrollbar then I told the resize to be 'none'

I expected the resize handle to disappear which it did but the overflow is just wrapping down to the next line instead of scrolling.

```
<s:textarea name="newsString" cols="65" rows="17" style="overflow: scroll; resize: none;"></s:textarea>
```

So how should I properly go about hiding the resize handle and still having it scroll? If that is at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Struts2 tags, `class` and `style` attributes are named `cssClass` and `cssStyle`.

This will work:

```
<s:textarea name="newsString" cols="65" rows="17" 
            cssStyle="overflow: scroll; resize: none;" />
```

The fact that you wasn't getting compilation errors due to an inexistent attribute, is because `<s:textarea>` tag (like `<s:file>` tag and maybe some others), has

> Dynamic Attributes Allowed: **true**

([as specified in the official documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/textarea.html)), that means that all you will write (that is not a valid Struts2 attribute) will be reported in the HTML without any parsing (so when, for example, `CSS3-4` and `HTML5` specifics introduces new features, there is no need to alter the tag to stay up to date, let's think to the multiple="multiple" attribute in `<s:file />`...)