# Struts2 Select tag : required vs. requiredLabel

Tags: struts2, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

I am upgrading struts2 (core) from 2.1.8.1 to 2.3.31 and having the following problem: After upgrading all the jars, compiling the app, running it, and accessing the page, I get the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/ui/SelectTag.setRequired(Ljava/lang/String;)V

So I do a little digging and find the following report: [Source compatibility report for the struts2-core library between 2.3.8 and 2.3.12 versions](https://abi-laboratory.pro/java/tracker/compat_report/struts2-core/2.3.8/2.3.12/16bc9/src_compat_report.html)
Basically showing that :

1. `AbstractUITag.setRequiredLabel ( String requiredLabel )  :  void` - added.
2. `AbstractUITag.setRequired ( String required )  :  void` - was removed

Now, the [docs](https://struts.apache.org/docs/select.html) for Select element, mention the following, that `requiredLabel` is defined as *If set to true, the rendered element will indicate that input is required* of type Boolean.

So, I am kind of lost here, should I use `requiredLabel=true` or just drop the `required` attribute and validate in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `requiredLabel` attribute will generate an `*` to render visually that the field is mandatory.

[The attribute was called `required` in old versions of the tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27225447/1654265), but then HTML5 specs came out with the `required` attribute, that has nothing to do with the asterisk and instead instructs a browser to not allow the submission of a form with those fields empty, and hence the new versions of the tags had to change it in order to make possible to use the HTML5 version, while keeping the asterisk functionality available, just under another name: `requiredLabel`.

Your only *needed* operation is:

> find every occurrence of `required="true"`, replace it with `requiredLabel="true"`.

The *suggested* operation is:

> find every occurrence of `required="true"`,
>
> replace it with `requiredLabel="true" required="required"`

,so you'll get the best of both worlds.

Also pay attention to useless but potentially existing `required="false"` occurrencies.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, I got it now. Just one comment - in struts 2.3 there is no attribute "required" so setting still fails.

Comment: It won't fail due to [dynamic attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17821833/1654265). Feel free to upvote :)

Answer (score -1):

The setRequiredLabel seems to have the same method signature as setRequired, save the method names. Considering the fact that writing the validation code manually may take more time and may also have a chance of being less efficient than using the setRequiredLabel, it may be a good option to use setRequiredLabel instead of reinventing the wheel.
It may also be worthwhile considering the impact of this version on other areas in your code that may use the setRequired, and keep the working between the classes as consistent as possible.